# Create a dictionary (array) from CSV data

Tags: php, arrays, csv, dictionary, file

I need to write a function that takes temperature as an input and returns a dictionary with years as keys and number of days as values.

CSV file looks like this (year, month, day, hour, temperature):

```
2019,1,1,0,0.1
2019,1,1,1,0.4
2019,1,1,2,0.8
2019,1,1,3,1.3
2019,1,1,4,1.8
...
2020,1,1,0,-3.9
```

The number of days is calculated by another function which I already have. It takes a year and a temperature and returns how many days in a given year the temperature was equal to or below the given temperature. Since the data is about hours, not days, the number of hours is found and then divided by 24.

The function:

```
function getDaysUnderTemp(int $targetYear, float $targetTemp): float {

    $file = fopen("data/temperatures-filtered.csv", "r");
    $hours = 0;

    while ($data = fgetcsv($file)) {
        if ($data[0] == $targetYear and $data[4] <= $targetTemp) {
            $hours ++;
        }
    }

    fclose($file);
    return $hours / 24;
}
```

So as an example `getDaysUnderTemp(2019, -10)` returns `13.92`.

This is a function I am asking about as I'm not sure how it might be done:

```
function getDaysUnderTempDictionary(float $targetTemp): array {
    $file = fopen("data/temperatures-filtered.csv", "r");

    while ($data = fgetcsv($file)) {
        ???
    }
    
    fclose($file);
    return [];
}
```

The problem is I don't understand how an already written function could be implemented in this new one, and then create a required dictionary from all this data. Without using classes.

Desired output of `getDaysUnderTempDictionary(-10)`:

```
Array
(
    [2019] => 3.88
    [2020] => 0.21
    [2021] => 13.92
)
```

Comment: Duplicate of the same question that was asked only a bit earlier, under a different nickname: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75497334/1427878

Comment: And of a question asked by the same account as this one, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just storing hours as a single variable, store it in an array indexed by year. Once done with the CSV, loop over the array and divide each by 24, same as you did before.

This code has a mock CSV file for demo purposes, but is otherwise the same as yours:

```php
function getDaysUnderTempDictionary(float $targetTemp): array {
    //This is just for mocking a CSV file
    $dataString = <<<EOT
2019,1,1,0,0.1
2019,1,1,1,0.4
2019,1,1,2,0.8
2019,1,1,3,1.3
2019,1,1,4,1.8
2020,1,1,0,-3.9
EOT;
    $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    fwrite($stream, $dataString);
    rewind($stream);
    
    $years = [];
    while ($data = fgetcsv($stream)) {
        $year = $data[0];
        if ($data[4] <= $targetTemp) {
            if(!isset($years[$year])){
                $years[$year] = 0;
            }
            $years[$year]++;
        }
    }
    foreach($years as $year => $hours){
        $years[$year] = $hours / 24;
    }
    return $years;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/RWFPK

Comment: thank you. but for some reason it does not loop over the hours and does not count them. it just basically returns 0.0416 (1 / 24)

Comment: found the problem. in ```if(!isset($hours[$year]))``` there should be ```$years``` instead of ```$hours```

Comment: Good catch, it was a last second refactor, I’ve updated it above, too